# Ajax Delete from mysql with PHP using custom popup alert box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this code, everything works fine but delete records from table command is not working.

Here is Head Section

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.phpzag.com/demo/delete-records-with-bootstrap-confirm-modal-using-php-mysql/script/bootbox.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="deleteRecords.js"></script>
```

Here is body code

```
<?php require('db_connect.php'); ?>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Comments</th>
<th>Actions</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM comments";
    $select = mysql_query($sql);
    while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($select)){
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $rows["usercom"]; ?></td>
<td>
<a class="delete_employee" data-emp-id="<?php echo $rows["id"]; ?>" href="javascript:void(0)">
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
</a></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

its deleteRecords.js code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.delete_employee').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var empid = $(this).attr('data-emp-id');
        var parent = $(this).parent("td").parent("tr");
        bootbox.dialog({
            message: "Are you sure you want to Delete ?",
            title: "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></i> Delete !",
            buttons: {
                success: {
                    label: "No",
                    className: "btn-success",
                    callback: function() {
                        $('.bootbox').modal('hide');
                    }
                },
                danger: {
                    label: "Delete!",
                    className: "btn-danger",
                    callback: function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'delete.php',
                        data: 'empid='+empid
                    })
                   .done(function(response){
                       bootbox.alert(response);
                       parent.fadeOut('slow');
                    })
                   .fail(function(){
                       bootbox.alert('Error....');
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

});

and here is delete.php

```
<?php require('db_connect.php');

if($_POST['empid']) {
$sql = "DELETE FROM comments WHERE id='".$_POST['empid']."'";
if($sql) {
echo "Record Deleted";
}
}
?>
```

Now, the issue is, When i click on Delete icon, and in popup alert, i confirm delete, the record disappear for the time being. but its not been deleted from the database actually, and when i refresh the page. that record appears again.

I don't understand why delete command in delete.php is not working.
Also, I want a little change in popup alert, when i click on confirm delete, one more popup appears with the result message that **Deleted Successfully**
I don't want to show this message. what to do. Plz Help me

Comment: Are you currently execute your `$sql` command ?

Comment: can you change to `data: {'empid' : empid}` in your ajax code and try? remove the line `bootbox.alert(response);` from the `.done` handler to remove the success message

Comment: Also the query is never executed here

Comment: You are only initialing query as string but not executing it

Comment: query is executed successfully. and yes, it is not showing now. Thanks a bunch dear

Comment: @Niladri What, if i am not showing records in table rows, and i am showing it in div. so what change i have to make in js file where     `var parent = $(this).parent("td").parent("tr");`

Comment: @Mian you have to select the div with the id if possible like `var parent = $("#mydiv")` where mydiv is the id

Comment: @Niladri yes it worked. Thank you so much brother.

Comment: @Niladri i am getting a problem again, if i have many divs in container div, so will it be fine if i only mention the container div id in    `var parent = $($container)` or in that case i hv to mention all parent divs names like 
   `$(this).parent("#check").parent("#checked").parent("#container");`

Comment: @Mian you can use the below selector `$("#containerdivid div");` to select all divs that are inside the container div where `containerdivid` is the id of the container div

Comment: @Niladri even if this container div contains spans? this container div has different buttons, for edit comment, delete comment, p tags etc. so when i use only divs and use $("#containerdivid div"); it works, but when i use spans and p tags then its not working, comment is deleted from database but don't disappear at once. but on refresh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IF condition are returning TRUE because $sql var has content, but your not executing the query.

Comment: My Gosh, i did mistake in executing. yes it worked. but only thing remains is not to show the 2nd alert with success query